# How to create bridge to use my wifi into VM?

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I want to use my wifi and create a bridge for my VM, so my VM gets its own IP address from my router and I can easily ssh into it.

When I create a bridge with nm-connection-editor, I see only the option for ethernet, not wifi. What should I do?

Comment: You create the bridge using your VM Host software's networking settings, not Network Manager. What is the VM Software? Is Ubuntu the host or the guest?

Comment: @user535733 the host is ubuntu. The only way I found to create a bridge in ubuntu as with nm-connection-editor.

Comment: What kind of virtualization software? Virtualbox? (Almost of them bundle a virtual network manager providing what you need out of the box) - Note that a host pci NIC will not be directly driven by a guest, but this is not the need you described

Comment: @cmak.fr virt-manager, which doesn't have option for bridge